# Can I pass XML into flash as a flashvar in AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flashvars

Is it possible to load xml as a flashvar? Basically I want to pull information from a server for a news ticker, but I want the info to be available as or before flash loads so that it appears to be instantaneous. Can xml be passed in as a flash var or do I need to break down the feed into individual vars that get passed in?

I'm not talking about passing a URL to flash, I mean that actual XML. Basically I just want all the data there and loaded on the same page as the flash so there's no load times.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is no, because flashvars come in as Strings. But you can turn a String into XML via one line of code:

var xml : XML = new XML( myString );

Comment: hmm... I've been playing with it and it seems like if there are any "" in the text, it breaks the embed codes. I'm thinking maybe it's not possible.

Comment: You can use backslashes before your "", like this \"\"
This way it won't break the embeded code